# How do i use the Thread Local Storage (TLS)?

Tags: c++, windows

If I have thread handlers, how do i put them into TLS? MSDN doesn't provide any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN, there is a link to [example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the article.

Answer (score 2):

Using the power of Google I found an example on the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)